# What are .NET asynchronous methods and how do you call them?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I've noticed that certain .NET classes contain asynchronous methods and some classes like System.Net.Http.HttpClient only expose asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET introduced asynchronous methods several years ago.  The general idea is that you can call an asynchronous method and while it is processing, you can execute other stuff while you’re waiting for your asynchronous method to complete.

What makes a method asynchronous?  By convention, an asynchronous method contains the word *Async* in the name of the method.  An asynchronous method must use the *Await* keyword at least once and return a Task object.

When you call an asynchronous method, you can precede the method call with the word Await.  When this line of code is encountered, the asynchronous method will start executing, and instead of waiting for it, your code will continue until the result of the asynchronous method is used.

For example:

```
Async Function GetFullNameAsync() As Task(Of String)

        Dim FirstNameTask = GetFirstNameAsync()
        Dim MiddleNameTask = GetMiddleNameAsync()
        Dim LastNameTask = GetLastNameAsync()

        Dim FirstName = Await FirstNameTask
        Dim MiddleName = Await MiddleNameTask
        Dim LastName = Await LastNameTask

        Return FirstName & " " & MiddleName & " " & LastName

End Function
```

Let’s say each of one these “Name” methods take 2 seconds to return a response:

```
Async Function GetFirstNameAsync() As Task(Of String)

        Await Task.Delay(2000)

        Return "Steve"

End Function
```

If you were to call each of these methods synchronously, then it would take a total of 6 seconds to get the full name.  However, by calling the methods using the *Await* keyword, you get the result in 2 seconds, because all 3 names are retrieved at the same time!

This is essentially why it is recommended to NOT call an asynchronous method without the *Await* keyword.  You miss out on the benefits of the method being asynchronous to begin with.  However, there is a strict requirement in that in order to use the *Await* keyword, you must be calling it inside an asynchronous method.

So, if you’re calling the asynchronous method from a “regular” synchronous method, you can’t use *Await*.  What to do?  Simply call the method but use the .Result property.  Calling the .Result property (or .Wait if the method doesn’t return anything) will automatically just wait or “block the code” until the asynchronous method returns its desired value.

For example:

```
Function GetFullName() As String

        Dim FirstName = GetFirstNameAsync().Result()
        Dim MiddleName = GetMiddleNameAsync().Result()
        Dim LastName = GetLastNameAsync().Result()

        Return FirstName & " " & MiddleName & " " & LastName

End Function
```

You must be a little careful here.  Due to the way asynchronous methods inherently are, this could result in a deadlock in your application.  I think you’ll be fine if you’re calling this in a console app, but in an application with an event loop, like ASP.NET Web Forms or Windows Forms, you may want to do something like the following:

```
Function GetFullNameAlt() As String

        Dim FirstNameTask = Task.Run(Function() GetFirstNameAsync())
        Dim MiddleNameTask = Task.Run(Function() GetMiddleNameAsync())
        Dim LastNameTask = Task.Run(Function() GetLastNameAsync())

        Dim FirstName = FirstNameTask.Result()
        Dim MiddleName = MiddleNameTask.Result()
        Dim LastName = LastNameTask.Result()

        Return FirstName & " " & MiddleName & " " & LastName

End Function
```

This may be your best option for calling asynchronous methods in a synchronous environment.  This allows you to take advantage of the asynchronicity of the method without using the *Await* keyword and without being inside an asynchronous method.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading Stephen Cleary's series of blog posts on asynchronous programming, especially if you're going to be working in an ASP.NET context.

Comment: @Craig Thanks. Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: @Craig Nevermind. Found it. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html